# Nodejs Express query mongolab for a single entry using data from a form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, forms, express, mlab

I am a Nodejs newbie and am trying to search my mongolab database for an entry(that I know exists) using data from a form entry. Here is my code:

```
var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
const port = 3000;

MongoClient.connect('mongodb://<user>:<password>@ds111882.mlab.com:11882/serene-brushlands-55292-db', function(err, database) {
    if(err) return console.log(err);
    db = database
    app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('Server started at port:'+port);
    });
});

// var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:false });
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/index.html');
});

app.all('/addUser', function(req, res) {
    res.render('addUser');
    db.collection('users').save(req.body, function(err, result) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);
        console.log('saved to database');
    })
    console.log(req.body);
});


app.get('/outputAll', function(req, res) {
    db.collection('users').find().toArray(function (err, result) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    res.render('outputall', {users:result});
    });
});

app.get('/Search', function(req, res) {
    res.render('search');
    var query = {}
    console.log(req.body);
    if (req.body.username)
    {
    console.log("true");
    query.username = req.body.username;
    }
    db.collection('users').find({query}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    console.log(1);
    });
});
```

The `search` part is meant to accomplish this objective. But I am not sure how to collect the query from my input form and pass it to the this `app.get` and have it passed to the database where it is searched. Here is the `Search` ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>MY APP</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto;width: 500px;">
    <form action="/Search" method="GET" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 200px; margin-top: 100px;">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" name="username"  style="margin: 20px auto; font-size: 50px;">
        <!-- <input type="file" name="picture"> -->
        <button type="submit"  style="margin: 20px auto; font-size: 50px;">Submit</button>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output on the console when I run this is:

> Server started at port:3000
>
> {}
>
> []
>
> {}
>
> []

I was expecting the `{}` to be the `form` data and the `[]` to be the result of searching the query in the database.
Please help!

**----------------EDIT-----------------**

The response I am receiving after changing the form method to `post` is :

```
Request body  = undefined
[ { _id: 59384e971f8bc03d4ef35486 },
  { _id: 59385153304b40406d49ad28 },
  { _id: 5938519c58358a40e55cded8 },
  { _id: 593889193448616054a95b0d },
  { _id: 59388945b268a0607bce2e9c },
  { _id: 5938894bb268a0607bce2e9d,
    username: 'asfj',
    specialty: 'lkjsf',
    address: 'lkjsdf' },
  { _id: 59388ae40d294f6168c55ccf },
  { _id: 59388ddeba074c630a1a8861 },
  { _id: 5938922a9f549f667c9f7a91 },
  { _id: 5938c29c453e40053965e9eb },
  { _id: 5938c2f9453e40053965e9ec,
    username: 'abc',
    specialty: 'dsfsaddfjk',
    address: 'oidjfioa' },
  { _id: 5938c327453e40053965e9ed } ]
Request body  = abc
[ { _id: 59384e971f8bc03d4ef35486 },
  { _id: 59385153304b40406d49ad28 },
  { _id: 5938519c58358a40e55cded8 },
  { _id: 593889193448616054a95b0d },
  { _id: 59388945b268a0607bce2e9c },
  { _id: 5938894bb268a0607bce2e9d,
    username: 'asfj',
    specialty: 'lkjsf',
    address: 'lkjsdf' },
  { _id: 59388ae40d294f6168c55ccf },
  { _id: 59388ddeba074c630a1a8861 },
  { _id: 5938922a9f549f667c9f7a91 },
  { _id: 5938c29c453e40053965e9eb },
  { _id: 5938c2f9453e40053965e9ec,
    username: 'abc',
    specialty: 'dsfsaddfjk',
    address: 'oidjfioa' },
  { _id: 5938c327453e40053965e9ed } ]
```

I have changed the `add.get('Search',fn)` to :

```
app.all('/Search', function(req, res) {
    res.render('search');
    db.collection('users').find().toArray(function(err, result) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    var query = {}
    console.log("Request body  = "+req.body.username);
    // if (req.body.username)
    // {
    //     console.log(req.body);
    //     query.username = req.body.username;
    // }

    console.log(result);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/Search` request you're making is using `GET` request & not the `POST`. If you want to access form data through request body I suggest you use `POST` method or else access url parameters for `GET` method.

After receiving data you can then format it for the query by creating an object.

Comment: I don't know how to create an object for the query. Could you please expand on that?

Comment: It's just plain javascript object. If you're asking me how to query then I'll need to know what data you're receiving. You're on right path just do for the remaining fields what you've done for username. Once you receive data it'll be clear to you, I suppose. If not feel free to comment with your data & what you want to query.

Comment: Yep it seems a bit clearer. I have edited the question and added the details now.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want the result to be of query and what fields you have in schema. I guess you've solved ur problem. If not refer @necilAlbayrak answer for query.

Answer (score 1):

In mongoose you should find documents in your db by sending objects as parameters.
For example if you are looking for a person in your database with name john you use

`db.collection('users').find({name: 'John'}).then(function(resp){}).catch(function(err){})`

{name: 'John'} is your javascript object mongoose will use while executing query

since you say you are new it is useful to learn this pattern called promises.